# Schema causing uberimage build failure

Tags: clojure, compilation, leiningen, uberjar

I'm developing a simple hello world web app in Clojure. However, after I added the [Schema](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema) library to my project, I started getting the error below when trying to build an uberjar using `lein uberjar`. Strangely, the app still passes the unit tests and runs without errors when started using `lein dev`.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol:
>   missing-required-key in this context, compiling:(server/api.clj:21:17)
>     at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6464)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$VectorExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3126)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6447)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$MapExpr.parse(Compiler.java:2981)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6453)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$MapExpr.parse(Compiler.java:2981)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6453)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.access$100(Compiler.java:38)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6050)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6644)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6100)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6644)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6644)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6100)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6644)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6100)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6644)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6100)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6644)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5217)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3846)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6642)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5217)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3846)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6642)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.access$100(Compiler.java:38)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:538)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6644)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7221)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7292)     at
>   clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:398)  at
>   clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:438)     at
>   clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)     at
>   clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)  at
>   clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)     at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)   at
>   clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)   at
>   clojure.core$compile$fn__5071.invoke(core.clj:5652)   at
>   clojure.core$compile.invoke(core.clj:5651)    at
>   user$eval9$fn__16.invoke(form-init1857067608391167398.clj:1)  at
>   user$eval9.invoke(form-init1857067608391167398.clj:1)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6693)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)    at
>   clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)     at
>   clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)    at
>   clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:307)  at
>   clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)    at
>   clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)  at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)   at
>   clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)     at
>   clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)  at
>   clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)    at
>   clojure.main.main(main.java:37) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to resolve symbol: missing-required-key in this context    at
>   clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:221)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.resolveIn(Compiler.java:6940)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:6884)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSymbol(Compiler.java:6845)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6427)     ... 153 more
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   resolve symbol: missing-required-key in this context,
>   compiling:(server/api.clj:21:17)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6464)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$VectorExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3126)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6447)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$MapExpr.parse(Compiler.java:2981)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6453)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$MapExpr.parse(Compiler.java:2981)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6453)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.access$100(Compiler.java:38)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6050)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6644)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6100)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6644)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6644)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6100)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6644)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6100)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6644)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6100)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6644)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5217)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3846)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6642)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3719)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5217)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3846)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6642)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.access$100(Compiler.java:38)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:538)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6644)  at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7221)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7292)     at
>   clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:398)  at
>   clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:438)     at
>   clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)     at
>   clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)  at
>   clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)     at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)   at
>   clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)   at
>   clojure.core$compile$fn__5071.invoke(core.clj:5652)   at
>   clojure.core$compile.invoke(core.clj:5651)    at
>   user$eval9$fn__16.invoke(form-init1857067608391167398.clj:1)  at
>   user$eval9.invoke(form-init1857067608391167398.clj:1)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6693)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)    at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)    at
>   clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)     at
>   clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)    at
>   clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:307)  at
>   clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)    at
>   clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)  at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)   at
>   clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)     at
>   clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)  at
>   clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)    at
>   clojure.main.main(main.java:37) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to resolve symbol: missing-required-key in this context    at
>   clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:221)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.resolveIn(Compiler.java:6940)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:6884)     at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSymbol(Compiler.java:6845)   at
>   clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6427)     ... 153 more
>   Compilation failed: Subprocess failed

Below is the source file where I use schema. For brevity, I've omitted the rest of my source files, but if anyone wants to see the rest, just ask.

```
(ns server.api
  (:require [aleph.http :as http]
            [compojure.api.sweet :refer :all]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [com.stuartsierra.component :as component]
            [ring.middleware.reload :refer [wrap-reload]]
            [ring.util.http-response :refer :all]
            [schema.core :as s]
            [server.logging :refer [wrap-exception-logging wrap-request-logging] :as log]))

(s/defschema Greeting
  {:hello s/Str
   s/Keyword s/Any})

(defn app [db]
  (api
   {:format {:formats [:json-kw]}}
   (middlewares [wrap-request-logging
                 wrap-exception-logging]
                (swagger-ui "/docs" :swagger-docs "/endpoints")
                (swagger-docs "/endpoints"
                 {:info {:title "Hello World Api"}})

                (GET* "/greet" []
                      :summary "Greets someone by name."
                      :description "Greets a person by name, telling them about
                                    the database configuration we're using as well."
                      :return Greeting
                      :query-params [name :- s/Str]
                      (ok {:hello name :with-db db}))

                (route/not-found (not-found {:error "Page not found."})))))

(defrecord Api
  [port env db logger]
  component/Lifecycle

  (start [{:keys [connection] :as component}]
    (if connection
      component
      (do (log/info "Starting Api at port" port "with env" env)
          (let [application (app db)
                handler (if (= env :dev) (wrap-reload application) application)
                conn (http/start-server handler {:port port :join? false})]
            (assoc component :connection conn)))))

  (stop [{:keys [connection] :as component}]
    (if-not connection
      component
      (do (log/info "Stopping Api")
          (.close connection)
          (assoc component :connection nil)))))

(defn new-api [port env]
  (->Api port env nil nil))
```

I've already tried disabling AOT compilation, since that seems to be the main difference between normal compilation and building an uberjar, but no dice. I also looked for the 'missing-required-key' key in the Schema source code and made sure it is quoted properly, it definitely seems to be, since if I change it Schema's tests start failing.

What else is different about the compilation process when creating an uberjar compared to compiling normally? Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause is that the `swagger-docs`-route is given an invalid input (no `:version` given, see https://github.com/metosin/ring-swagger/blob/master/src/ring/swagger/swagger2_schema.clj#L13). When it's added, it works as expected.

Still, the given exception was really bad, and is fixed now in the latest SNAPSHOT - uses defaults for missing fields and thus does not do compile-time schema check for it.

Also, would recommend not AOTing the whole app. See https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api/issues/129

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen that error before (and we deploy all of our services with schema and uberjar).   It looks like line 21 is the swagger-docs middleware; can you try removing that and see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Removing line 21/22 did indeed solve the issue. Now I need to figure out why swagger is making it fail... What made you suspect this was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I did react on that you use `:refer :all`, it is preferred to use `:refer [list of symbols used in code]`. This probably not the error here, but it makes the code much easier to dive into for someone who don't know so much about the libraries.

I looked into the `compojure.api.sweet`-namespace and I see that Zach Tellmans [Potemkin](https://github.com/ztellman/potemkin) is used to "import" all functions from various namespaces into your namespace `service.api`. Maybe this renders problems when creating a jar.

Could you try to require the `swagger-ui` and `swagger-docs` from their original namespace by adding this row to the require?

`[compojure.api.swagger swagger-ui swagger-docs]`

If this doesn't work but at least gives another error message (maybe) try to `require` all the other symbols used explicitly.

Comment: The more I look into `compojure.api`, the less I understand how it evaluates its routes table, and debugging this should be nightmare. I would actually recommend using another, more explicit library to facilitate Swagger.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I tried your suggestions, explicitly referring everything, but I still get just the same error message. So is the issue here likely something like namespace conflicts between different libraries I'm using?

Comment: I think there is some conflict in the two nested macros. Maybe `macroexpand` and see if the resulting expressions compiles...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but try running `lein deps :tree` and see what the transitive dependencies are. It may be that multiple libraries are depending on different, incompatible versions of the same dependency. I've run into this before, but I have no idea why it would only happen when packaged in the uberjar.